# How to add vertical and horizontal space from text to top of <textarea> without padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, textarea

Normally you'd just use padding for this but I have some js that requires the dimensions and that would require me to do a lot of pixel-perfecting especially if I'm planning to use that js multiple times.

There's a `[text-indent][1]` property for horizontal spacing but it only works for the first line

**What it is right now:**
[image]

**Roughly what I need:**
[image]

Comment: There are only padding and margin. But you can always put a div inside another div.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Wrap the textarea in an element with the same background color and apply the offset style to it instead: `<div class="bg-black"><div class="bg-orange"><textarea class="bg-orange"></textarea></div></div>` — if this answers your question then I can write it as one — if not, what did I miss?

Comment: @jsejcksn I still want for the whole area to remain clickable so your solution is not quite there, I do think that James Mwaura's solution is a way tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Grid component for example, and inside is a Typography component then you could do this

```
<Grid sx={{ display: 'flex', marginLeft:1,}}> <Typography>text here</Typography></Grid>
```

You can as well do this in a css file.

Comment: I think that's my goal is being lazy, I mean efficient and this sort of goes against it, it's just simpler to pixel perfect it each time. It is a solution to the question totally though